# Load a cubemap from DDS cubemap file with three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

How to use DDS cubemaps in three.js for scene backgrounds (or skyboxes)? In current time, I explode cubemap DDS to six images and load them with THREE.CubeTextureLoader(). May be other simple way exists? Like this:

```
var skybox = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/files/skybox.dds');
scene.background = skybox;
```

Comment: Try the DDSLoader. Working example in the source here: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_compressed.html and Find the DDSLoader extra here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/DDSLoader.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the DDSLoader

```
var loader = new THREE.DDSLoader();
var skybox = loader.load( '/files/skybox.dds' );
scene.background = skybox;
```

The DDSLoader class must be added to your application: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/DDSLoader.js

Comment: Cubemap texture loaded normally with DDSLoader: But error occured if attempt using them as scene.background: `TypeError: mipmaps is undefined in three.js:17959:22`

Comment: Be sure the pixel length of each side of your image is a power of 2.